# Replace Linefeeds in Text file

Tags: c#

I got a text file where each row ends with **CRLF** which is fine,  but file got some rows with **LF** within the row content.

Am trying to replace the **LF** which are within the row content as below:

```
var fileContent = File.ReadAllText(fileName);
fileContent = Regex.Replace(fileContent, @"(?<!\r)\n", " ");
File.WriteAllText(fileName, fileContent);
```

This works fine.  But when am trying to deal with large file (more than 150mb), throws memory exception.

Tried with

`List<string> text = File.ReadAllLines(filePath).ToList();`
to read lines and replace by line.  But this doesn't work as it splits like on **LF**

How can I force to split lines by **CRLF**

Comment: Why not read input file (and write output file) line-by-line?

Comment: @Dmitry: I tried to read line by line and replace .. but file.ReadLine(), splits the line by \n as well \r\n ... i just want the line where its ends with \r\n and replace the \n within the line.

Comment: OK. Why not read to small fixed buffer using `StreamReader.Read` (or `TextReader.ReadBlock`)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [File.ReadLines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503.aspx) that returns [IEnumerable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0.aspx) which means that it **only** extract one line at a time when needed using the [yield](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k7k7cf0.aspx) functionality.
After successfully writing to **anotherFilename** we then deleting **fileName** and moving **anotherFilename** to his position.

```
foreach (var line in File.ReadLines(fileName))
{
    File.WriteAllText(anotherFilename, line + Environment.NewLine);
}
File.Delete(fileName);
File.Move(anotherFilename, filename);
```

Note: Haven't been tested.